# Twilio modifying APIs parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I would like to ask if I can modify the current API of the same service and add one parameter to identify APIs calls "source"

for example, I would like to know from were I got the call; is it from WhatsApp chatting, application or from Website
So I can have a report with how many usage for each platform

Appreciate your support and help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it will be your backend application calling the Twilio API’s, you have this insight on your end you can gather.

Comment: Dear Alan, thank you for your replay and your kind support, science it is my first time dealing with APIs; could you please explain it more for me ?